# Mavros actautor topic conflict

Tags: ros, actuator, px4, mavros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this tutorial here: https://pixhawk.org/dev/ros/ground_rover

I have sussessfully got this to work using the mavros in the past but I have since built mavros from source and now I am getting this error when I try to publish to the **/mavros/actuator_control** topic:

```
[ERROR] [1444603771.272545431]: Client [/mavros] wants topic /mavros/actuator_control to have datatype/md5sum [mavros_msgs/ActuatorControl/9eea0a80c88944fe2fb67f3b3768854b], but our version has [mavros/ActuatorControl/ba56d1663d64ac435b80a3508d6ce1d2]. Dropping connection.
```

Not sure how it is relevant but I can see there is a different folder structure with my workspace: **~/catkin_ws/src/mavros/mavros_msgs/msg/ActuatorControl.msg**

Compared to this: **/opt/ros/indigo/share/mavros/msg/ActuatorControl.msg**

How can I resolve the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218972/mavros-actautor-topic-conflict/) by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind I got it. Was using the wrong header. Should be `#include <mavros_msgs/ActuatorControl.h>` instead of `#include <mavros/ActuatorControl.h>` and then `nh.advertise<mavros_msgs::ActuatorControl>` instead of `nh.advertise<mavros::ActuatorControl>`

So painfully obvious now that i know, should I laugh or cry ;)

---

Originally posted by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) with karma: 94 on 2015-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0